# Trouble feeling rhythm in section

Tags: piano, rhythm, pop-music

[image]

The song is in 4/4 but this section is giving me a hard time feeling the rhythm. Clearly it can be divided into 16ths, but the pattern feels like triplets after the first note. For example after the first note (Ab) it's all ascending notes.

- Db - Gb - Db
- Db - Gb - Ab
- Db - F - Db
- Db - F - Ab
- Db - Db

Is there a way I can learn to feel the notated rhythm and avoid feeling "triplets" instead?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the question is "How do I improve the playing of this rhythm?"

Here is the approach i would take:

- Practice with a metronome.
- Play slowly. You can make it so slow that you have a metronome beep on each sixteenth note, with the quarter notes accented.
- Count out loud while playing at first.
- Play it so slowly you get it all correct and can hear where the notes land. I am mentioned play slowly twice because if you can't hear, feel, play it slowly you will never be able to at speed
- If you hearing this a triplets, leave your metronome on sixteenths and only play the starting note for each triplet while counting out all the sixteenths. Make sure to play the fingering as if you were playing the notes between. This will help you internalize where you are hearing the accents and where they fall in to the overall rhythm.
- If you have the ability to sequence this with midi do so, slow it down, listen to it. Count along with it. Even try using this as a crutch to play along with. I would recommend sequencing a click to go along with it so you can feel the beat.
- Tap your foot on the beat to help solidify the feel.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a temporary track (F clef with 4 Gb2 quarter notes in the first measure, ie) parallel to your melody track)
2. Increase the volume of the temporary track to maximum and reduce your melody track volume to medium.
3. Temporarily reduce BPM to 90 for both the tracks.
4. Play both tracks together and listen with repeating measure loop till you feel the beats 4/4.
5. Now remove the temporary track
6. Reset your melody track's BPM and volume

Note: If you have no midi tools, try [Music Tool Kit android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.loa.musictoolkit)